# Natbib and bibhang don't get along with numbers or super

Tags: indentation, natbib

I am using natbib.sty chicago.bst as my bibtex style sheets.

My natbib call looks like

```
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress,super]{natbib}
```

when I try to change the hanging indent in my bibliography nothing happens:

```
\setlength \bibhang{1in}
```

However, if I remove the `numbers` and `super` options from the `natbib` options, the hanging indent happens?  It appears that `bibhang` doesn't work with the numbers and super options?  Any clue whats going on here? I'm stumped and have spent the better part of the afternoon searching for an answer.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While it might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192/). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the `natbib` documentation,

> The list of references for author–year styles uses a hanging
>   indentation format: the first line of each reference is flush left,
>   the following lines are set with an indentation from the left margin.
>   This indentation is `1em` by default but may be changed by redefining
>   (with `\setlength`) the length parameter `\bibhang`.

This suggests that `\bibhang` will have effect with author-year schemes, but you are using the `numbers` option, so `\bibhang` won't have any effect.

One possible workaround would be to redefine the `thebibliography` environment as implemented in `report.cls`. Here's what you would have to add to your preamble  (change the value of `\mybibindent` according to your needs):

```
\newlength\mybibindent
\setlength\mybibindent{1in}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\chapter*{\bibname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\dimexpr\labelsep+\mybibindent\relax\itemindent-\mybibindent% new
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother
```