# How to remove hanging indentation from bibliographic entries

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I would like to use a bibliography style that aligns the text of the second and later lines of each reference entry with the text of the first. I have been using `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` but, as can be seen from in image below, the text of each line is not aligned. Which styles will achieve this? Thanks...

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove the hanging indentation, you needn't change bibliography styles. Just set the `\bibhang` length parameter to zero.

Assuming the Alziary et al entry is in a file called `adk.bib`, running latex, bibtex, and latex twice more on the MWE below results in the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{adk}
\end{document}
```

Remark: You should encase the words "P.D.E.", "Asian", and "Analytical" in the `title` field in curly braces to prevent them from being converted to lowercase.

Comment: Haha - yeah I should; just lazy! Thanks for your help, again, Mico.

Comment: Should this also work when using `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`? I still have the indentation mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Mico It seems that the answer is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25502/natbib-and-bibhang-dont-get-along-with-numbers-or-super?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Hi there. I did exactly the same thing as @Mico suggested, but the second line still did not align at the first line. I used separated bib file for each chapter. Any suggestions?

Comment: @kmmm - Which document class do you employ? Do you use a bibliography style that generates authoryear citation call-outs?

Comment: @Mico, I used \usepackage[numbers, sort&compress, comma]{natbib} and \usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib} in my preamble. Then, I used apalike in my Chapter1.tex file via \include{Chapter1} on my main file.

Comment: @kmmm - This sounds very confusing: `apalike` is a bib style that can only create authoryear-style citation call-outs yet you request numeric-style citation call-outs via ` \usepackage[numbers, ...]{natbib}`. Please post a *new query* in which you (a) lay out what you-re doing and (b) state what you would like to achieve.

Comment: @Mico - I'll make a new question as your suggestion.