# Alignment numbered apalike bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apa-style

I prefer the `apalike` bibliography style with the number in brackets in front (see also [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137075/how-to-remove-hanging-indentation-from-bibliographic-entries) and [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25502/natbib-and-bibhang-dont-get-along-with-numbers-or-super)). However what I am curious about is how to align the first and subsequent text lines neatly next to the number in brackets.

[image: Example]

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I know how to do this with `biblatex`, but this is not apalike bib style, as far as I know: it is a numeric style.

Comment: Could you give an example? I would like to have something similar to apa style but then with squared numbers

Comment: Apa style would label something like `Alziary & al. 1997`, possibly between brackets, since it an `authoryear` style.

Answer (score 5):

You can update some of the settings loaded by the `thebibliography` environment to a set of fixed lengths:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{adk-1997,
  author  = {B Alziary and JP D{\'e}camps and PF Koehl},
  title   = {A {PDE} approach to {A}sian options: {A}nalytical and numerical evidence},
  journal = {Journal of Banking \& Finance},
  year    = {1997},
  volume  = {21},
  number  = {5},
  pages   = {613-640}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\c@NAT@ctr\z@}{\c@NAT@ctr\z@
  \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{\makebox[1.2em][r]{##1\hfill}}%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{1.2em}%
  \setlength{\labelsep}{.5em}%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

You can increase the two length measures `1.2em` that forms part of `\makelabel` and setting `\labelwidth` if you have more than 9 references.

Comment: +1 for assuring that the words Asian and Analytical aren't lowercased. :-)

Comment: Do you by any chance know how to make this work if the multibib package is used? I have posted [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579509/alignment-of-apalike-bibliography-style-with-multibib), because the solution here does not seem to work with this package.