# How to remove hanging in bibliography items?

Tags: natbib

I want to remove the hanging indentation as in the question-answer: [How to remove hanging indentation from bibliographic entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137075/how-to-remove-hanging-indentation-from-bibliographic-entries). 
[image]

I am writing a thesis and i use numerous packages..
I tried to give a minimal working example below.. The bibliography style is actually apalike, but in order to change bibsymbol [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eybar.jpg)] to 1. i used a copy of it as tapalike..

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{enumerate,letltxmacro}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}
\def\bibindent{0em}
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{dot}{. }
\captionsetup{labelsep=dot}
\addto\captionsturkish{\renewcommand\bibname{{\normalsize REFERENCES}}}
\makeatletter\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}\makeatother
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\leftmargin\labelwidth}{\leftmargin\labelwidth\labelsep=.4cm}{}{}
\bibliographystyle{tapalike}
\begin{document}
THERMAL...\cite{pankaj2011}.
Convection ...\cite{benard1901}.
\bibliography{tezbib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please add your bibfile (using `begin{fileconents*}` or posting here)?

Comment: @Skillmon i am using a jabref file and i dont know how to post it here :(

Comment: The hanging indent is caused by the `[numbers]` argument to natbib. But I don't have a solution yet.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't find any solution yet (time is limitted and documentation poor). I hope you find someone more experienced than me or the solution yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what I have done in the preamble exactly, 
but this code seems to solve the problem. 
Thanks to @Gonzalo Medina and @Skillmon: [Natbib and bibhang don't get along with numbers or super](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25502/natbib-and-bibhang-dont-get-along-with-numbers-or-super)
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{enumerate,letltxmacro}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{dot}{. }
\captionsetup{labelsep=dot}
\addto\captionsturkish{\renewcommand\bibname{{\normalsize REFERENCES}}}
\bibliographystyle{tapalike}
\newlength\mybibindent
\setlength\mybibindent{7pt}
\bibliographystyle{tapalike}
\makeatletter\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}\makeatother
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
 {\chapter*{{\vspace*{-3.5em}}\centerline\bibname}%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
  \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
       {\settowidth\mybibindent{\@biblabel{#1. }}%
\setlength\labelsep{\mybibindent}
 \leftmargin\dimexpr\labelwidth
        \@openbib@code
        \usecounter{enumiv}
        \let\p@enumiv\@empty
        \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
  \sloppy
  \clubpenalty4000
  \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
  \widowpenalty4000%
  \sfcode`\.\@m}
 {\def\@noitemerr
   {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
THERMAL...\cite{pankaj2011}.
Convection ...\cite{benard1901}.
\cite{perkins2011}
\cite{rayleigh1916}
\cite{boussinesq1903}
\cite{roh2001}
\cite{kaya2009}
\cite{cannon1980}
\cite{morimoto1992}
\cite{robinson2001}
\bibliography{tezbib}
\end{document}
```